# DateTime weekday issue in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I am using the following:

```
$endtime = new DateTime(date('r', '1329717600'));
$endtime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
echo $endtime->format('w - l');
```

It should be outputting "1 - Monday"; but it is instead outputting "0 - Sunday"...

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's technically correct - the time/date on that timestamp would have been Sunday 10pm in LA, Monday 6am in UTC.

http://www.convert-unix-time.com/?t=1329717600

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct... I got confused because PHP considers Monday the first day of the week in some places, instead of Sunday.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
$endtime = new DateTime(date('r', '1329717600'), new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
echo $endtime->format('w - l');
```

[PHP documentation comment](http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.settimezone.php#94784) on the `setTimezone` function:

> The timestamp value represented by the DateTime object is not modified
>   when you set the timezone using this method.  Only the timezone, and
>   thus the resulting display formatting, is affected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$endtime = new DateTime;
$endtime->createFromFormat('U', 1329717600, new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
echo $endtime->format('w - l');
```